# How to Compare to Object class?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I make comparisons to the Object class?

I tried

`if ("0.0".equals(price) ||"0.0".equals(quantity))`

and

`if: (price.equals("0.0") ||quantity.equals("0.0"))`

In the last else it always prints `0.0` but nothing happen with if!!

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){for (int i = model1.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Object price = model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 8);
        Object quantity = model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 11);
        //if ("0.0".equals(price) ||"0.0".equals(quantity)) 
       if (price.equals("0.0") ||quantity.equals("0.0"))
        {
            model1.removeRow(i);
            System.out.println("price&: "+price);
            System.out.println("quantity&: "+quantity);
        }else{
            System.out.println("price: "+price);
            System.out.println("quantity: "+quantity);
        }
    }
       }
```

Comment: What is the type of `price` and `quantity`? I assume it's a `Number` of some sort rather than a `String`? Use `getClass()` to confirm.

Comment: What does your model hold for that column? Strings? doubles? When asking such questions, why post snippets that we can't compile or test? Please do consider putting in the worthwhile effort of creating and posting a valid [mcve], a very small program that we can compile, run and debug.

Comment: 1) why use the type `Object`? 2) your condition will only hold if `price` is A: a `String` and B: has the value `"0.0"`.

Comment: it is float from database but in a table should be string right?? any way i converted the Objects to Strings and i test String and it worked..

Comment: `"... but in a table should be string right?"` -- No. Usually this is not correct.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Full Of Eels    thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Java, calling equals on an object uses the object's identity.  Unless the calls to getQuantity and getPrice return Strings, they will not equal.  I would suggest that you not use raw Objects and use the actual types for your instances, override equals if you need to do things like compare Strings to Doubles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`Object`, `String` and `Double` classes all have a `.equals()` method, but they work differently.

For `Object` class comparison is made to the Object's hash code (the unique object ID) for equality. That comparison asks "Are these the *same object*?"

For String class, `.equals()` does a *string comparison*,  which is what I think you want, whether you're comparing `String` objects containing strings or string literals, or a combination of the two. Inside the JVM actually uses `string interning` where only *one copy* of a string's value is stored for the whole JVM, regardless of which object (or literal representation) refers to it, but that is invisible to you and doesn't matter for what you're doing... `String.equals()` compares string values and that's all you need to know.

For `Double` class the comparison is numeric.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    for (int i = model1.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Object price = model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 8);
        Object quantity = model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 11);
        if (price instanceof String && quantity instanceof String) {
            if (((String)price).equals("0.0") || ((String)quantity).equals("0.0")) {
                model1.removeRow(i);
                System.out.println("price&: "+price);
                System.out.println("quantity&: "+quantity);
            } else {
                System.out.println("price: "+price);
                System.out.println("quantity: "+quantity);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

The above is probably what you want, *assuming* `model1.getValueAt()` is returning a String type. If it isn't guaranteed to return a specific type then you'll need *check* the type of object it returns, before assigning or testing the value, to make sure it is downcast to the proper type.

But that's another subject.

Comment: i like your answer but it is object and netbeans asking me to cast to String.. i tried also float and the same..

Comment: I assume that means getValueAt() is returning Object because it can return different types.  So that means you need to know or check at runtime what type it is returning to be safe. If it doesn't always return String then trying casting it into String when it's another type will throw an exception. I will update the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer. That should give you a rough idea. If it could be returning other types you'd need to do `instanceof` to check those too. I haven't compiled this, but it should work or be very close to working.

Comment: i tried your code but didn't print anything. never in if  nether in else.. anyway my answer works for me thank you

Comment: Are you *sure* it's really working right and not just compiling and running because you're only comparing it to 0?  See my comment to your other answer, and, again, an upvote would not hurt. That doesn't mean the answer solves your problem, only that's it's informative/helpful/you like it.

Comment: it does not print anything it is the true and i will vote

Comment: Wow, well I guess I'm the one who learned something. I tested it and Object.toString() returns the string contents if the Object is a String. But the JavaDocs say it does something else: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: Not really sure why my code wouldn't work, but I don't have the environment to reproduce it, so... glad you figured something out.

Answer (score 1):

when i try:

```
if(object1 == null || object2 == null) {
 model1.removeRows();
      }
```

it works but only when the object is null and not content "0.0" so finally i convert the objects to Strings and here is what i did:

```
private void btn_clearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   for (int i = model1.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Object price = model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 8);
        Object quantity = model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 11);

        String s1=price.toString();
        String s2=quantity.toString();
        //if ("0.0".equals(price) ||"0.0".equals(quantity)) 
       if (s1.equals("0.0") ||s2.equals("0.0"))
        {
            model1.removeRow(i);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, Object *does* have a `.toString()` method but I seriously doubt that's what you want! It has to do with putting the object's name in String form, not the String contents if it's a String. String may be a special case, so I will test it, but I think it won't do what you want at runtime and you should print the String you get back.

Comment: E.g. log the string or step through with a debugger to examine the contents you get

Comment: i am always just using System.out... to test if the code is working

Comment: I prefer iOS programming, previously Objective-C but now Swift, also web technologies, but for my day job I support large Java infrastructure code and System.out.println, and logging would be completely inadequate or much of the debugging. At some point it pays off to get very comfortable with a debugger. I don't use it every time. For small amounts of code I use prints, but it should be something you're fast with and are ready to use on short notice, IMO.

Comment: If you are sure that `model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 8)` is a String, you can avoid assigning it to an `Object` and just do `String price = (String) model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 8)`.  It looks like you're making some assumptions about the type, and it looks very much like a Double.  Use the _Double.valueOf(String value)_ to turn that into a _Double_

Comment: i think it is the same with .toString(); and may be you can do it also like this:  model1.getValueAt(i, tbl_order_detail.getColumnCount() - 8).toString();

Comment: You can, but I would strongly encourage you to avoid Objects and Strings, use the type that most accurately represents your Data.  I'm going to go out on a limb and say that if you have numeric values, you might at some point be performing mathematical operations on them, you're going to need to use classes suitable for that anywho.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I think this is `JTable.getValueAt()` which returns an Object that can be different subclasses, so it's important not to assume the type unless you *KNOW* your application will never store the wrong type in the table and even then I'd be careful. But I've tested `Object.toString()` for `Double` and `String` now and contrary to the JavaDocs, it converts them the right way. Probably calls `.toString()` on the subclass if it exists before resorting to making-up a descriptive string of the Object's class name.